# Erro ao inserir dados no BD com PHP

Tags: php, crud

Ao tentar inserir dados no BD, apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

> ***Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'usuario' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\interface\cadastroUsuario.php:11 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\interface\cadastroUsuario.php on
>   line 11***

Formulário:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cadastro de Usuário</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form  action="../interface/cadastroUsuario.php" method="post" >
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Cadastro de Usuário</legend>
                    Nome:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="nome" required><br>
                    E-mail:<br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" required><br>
                    Senha:<br>
                    <input type="password" name="senha1" required><br>
                    Confirmar Senha:<br>
                    <input type="password" name="senha2" required><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar"><br>
                    <a href="../index.html">Voltar</a>
                </fieldset>
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

interface que recebe informações do formulário:

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha1 = $_POST['senha1'];
$senha2 = $_POST['senha2'];

if($senha1===$senha2){
    $senha = $senha1;
    //require_once '../classe/usuario.php';
    $obj = new usuario();
    $obj->inserir($nome, $email, $senha);
}else{
    echo "erro.";
}
interface cadastroUsuario {
    public function inserir($nome, $email, $senha);


}
```

Classe que faz inserção dos dados no BD:

```
<?php


class usuario implements cadastroUsuario{


    public function inserir($nome, $email, $senha) {
        //estebelecendo conexão com banco de dados
        $conexao = new conexao();
        $conn = $conexao->conectar();
        //instrução mysql para inserção de dados na tabela usuário do BD.
        $sql = "insert into usuario (nome, email, senha) values('$nome','$email','$senha');";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

            echo "Dados submetido com sucesso!";
        }else{
         echo 'Erro ao submeter os dados.';
        }

        }
    public function validaUsuario($dados){

        $conexao = new conexao();
        $conexao->conectar();
        $conn = $conexao->conectar();

        $sql = "select * from usuario where email= '$dados[0]' and senha= '$dados[1]';";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        //verificar se existe algum resultado na consulta
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($resultado)){

        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    } 
    }



?>
```

Classe que realiza conexão com BD:

```
<?php


class conexao {
    private $host="localhost";
    private $usuario="root";
    private $senha="";
    private $bd="sistema";

    function getHost() {
        return $this->host;
    }

    function getUsuario() {
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    function getSenha() {
        return $this->senha;
    }

    function getBd() {
        return $this->bd;
    }

    function setHost($host) {
        $this->host = $host;
    }

    function setUsuario($usuario) {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
    }

    function setSenha($senha) {
        $this->senha = $senha;
    }

    function setBd($bd) {
        $this->bd = $bd;
    }


    public function conectar(){
        $con=mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->bd);
        return $con;

    }
    public function desconectar(){
        $con=mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->bd);
        return mysqli_close($con);



    }
}
```

Comment: Aparentemente você não incluiu a classe usuário em `cadastroUsuario`, mas ao mesmo tempo implementou a interface nesse arquivo, que será necessário no arquivo da classe. Basicamente seu código está bastante confuso. Lembre-se que para a classe existir em um escopo, você precisa incluí-la

Comment: Como poderia deixar o código mais legitimo nesse caso?

Answer (score 1):

Tente separar as classes, interfaces e os arquivos que recebem dados do formulário em arquivos separados. Ex:

Arquivo: cadastroUsuario.php

```
interface cadastroUsuario {
    //codigo da interface
}
```

Arquivo usuario.php

```
require_once "cadastroUsuario.php"; //faz o include da interface

class usuario implements cadastroUsuario{
    //métodos da classe usuario
    //implementações da interface cadastroUsuario
}
```

Arquivo validaUsuario.php

```
require_once "usuario.php";

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha1 = $_POST['senha1'];
$senha2 = $_POST['senha2'];

if($senha1===$senha2){
    $senha = $senha1;
    $obj = new usuario();
    $obj->inserir($nome, $email, $senha);
}else{
    echo "erro.";
}
```

por fim, no seu form, altere a action para o arquivo "validaUsuario.php"

```
<form action="validaUsuario.php" .... >
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro estava no arquivo usuario.php

```
public function inserir($nome, $email, $senha) {
        //estebelecendo conexão com banco de dados
```

> //esqueci de chamar através do require once o conexao.php

```
        $conexao = new conexao();
        $conn = $conexao->conectar();
        //instrução mysql para inserção de dados na tabela usuário do BD.
        $sql = "insert into usuario (nome, email, senha) values('$nome','$email','$senha');";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

            echo "Dados submetido com sucesso!";
        }else{
         echo 'Erro ao submeter os dados.';
        }

        }
    public function validaUsuario($dados){

        $conexao = new conexao();
        $conexao->conectar();
        $conn = $conexao->conectar();

        $sql = "select * from usuario where email= '$dados[0]' and senha= '$dados[1]';";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        //verificar se existe algum resultado na consulta
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($resultado)){

        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    } 
    }



?>
```